# formating gcloud spanner queries

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-spanner

Up until recently my gcloud spanner queries where nicely presented as columns across the screen, with each output line representing a single row from the query. Recently however, for some unknown reason, the output is now displayed as row data presented in single column:value pair  down the screen, e.g.

```
PKey: 9moVr4HmSy6GGIYJyVGu3A==

Ty: Pf

IsNode: Y

P: None

IX: X
```

I have tried various --format command line options but alas have had no success in generating the original row-per-line-output format i.e. with columns presented across the screen as follows

```
PKey                     Ty   IsNode   P   IX    <-- columns names

9moVr4HmSy6GGIYJyVGu3A== Pf    Y      None  X.  <--- row data
```

What format option should I use ?.

Example of gcloud query:

```
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql test-sdk-db --instance=test-instance --sql="Select * from Block "
```

Thanks

Comment: I just tested this and my output is the table-like output by default. Can you add the output of `gcloud --version` to your question? For my install, I'm running `Google Cloud SDK 360.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

`gcloud` formats the results as a table if they're being written to a file, the usual [formatting rules](http://cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) apply otherwise.

So one easy way to see the table in the shell is to `tee` it somewhere:

```sh
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql test-sdk-db --instance=test-instance --sql="Select * from Block " \
| tee /dev/null
```

If you can't do that for some reason you can always get the same result with some `--format` surgery. To print the column names:

```
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql test-sdk-db --instance=test-instance --sql="Select * from Block " \
--format 'csv[no-heading, delimiter=" "](metadata.rowType.fields.name)'
```

And to print the rows:

```
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql test-sdk-db --instance=test-instance --sql="Select * from Block " \
--format 'csv[no-heading, delimiter="\n"](rows.map().flatten(separator=" "))'
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of `gcloud spanner databases execute-sql` is a result of broader changes in formatting to better support [accessibility standards for screen readers](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/accessibility).

There are two methods to receive results in the tabular format:

1. Set the `accessibility/screen_reader` configuration property to `false`.

   ```
   gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader false
   ```
2. Similar to the other suggestion about using formatting, you can use a `--format=multi(...)` option in your `gcloud` command:

   ```
   gcloud spanner databases execute-sql test-sdk-db \
       --instance=test-instance --sql="Select * from Block " \
       --format="multi(metadata:format='value[delimiter='\t'](rowType.fields.name)', \
                           rows:format='value[delimiter='\t']([])')"
   ```

   The caveat of this second method is that column names and values may not align due to differences in length.